# how to hide new ios7 "ipad", and "100%" battery icon overlay that is on top of everything?

Tags: ipad, text, ios7, overlay

How do I remove/hide the new ios7 overlay that says "ipad" on upper left, and "100%" battery icon on right?

They actually absorb touch inputs, so you cant put a button in the upper left. So stupid!!!

Older games don't show the overlay, so it must be something enabled by xcode5?

please help.

Comment: this overlay is called statusbar. That should get you started.

Comment: There are a lot of questions asking how to hide the status bar, go search!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=iOS+7+hide+status+bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you everyone. I did search, but I had the incorrect terms to find the answer. Thanks to Matthias, jack, and brian I found this answer that worked perfect for me. I placed this in my view controller.m

```
-(BOOL) prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To hide statusbar, you can add below keys in your app's plist file..

1. **"View controller-based status bar appearance"** and set it to **`NO`**
2. **"UIStatusBarHidden"** and set it to **`YES`**